# Failed to install golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt

Tags: go, influxdb

I trying install [InfluxDB](https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb) client. But installation failed. This is my trace:

```
go get -u -v -x github.com/influxdb/influxdb/client
github.com/influxdb/influxdb (download)
...
git remote -v
Fetching https://golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt?go-get=1
[1]    6625 segmentation fault (core dumped)  go get -u -v -x github.com/influxdb/influxdb/client
```

I did not find package *golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt* into **GOROOT** and **GOPATH**.

When I trying install **crypto/bcrypt**  I have this error:

```
go get -u -v golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt
Fetching https://golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt?go-get=1
[1]    7667 segmentation fault (core dumped)  go get -u -v golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt
```

How I can install *golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt*?

My golang version is **go version go1.4.2 gccgo**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found temporary solution.

Library *golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt* has mirror on [github](https://github.com/golang/crypto).

Create folder `src/golang.org/x/` into you `GOPATH`.

```
mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/
```

Then clone *crypto* from github.

```
cd $GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/
git clone git@github.com:golang/crypto.git
```

Answer (score 17):

I resolved it by using command:

`go get golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt`

Answer (score 0):

```
1 - cd /usr/local/go/src/
2 - sudo mkdir x
3 - cd x
4 - sudo git clone https://github.com/golang/crypto.git
5 - restart vscode
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.